# Limiting table to factors

Tags: r

I have a data set like below

```
particip    group   device  width   length  accep   thresh  rating  d-rating
1           RA      Dingo   nom     nom     Y       5       8       3
1           RA      Dingo   nom     long    Y       4       6       2
1           RA      Dingo   fat     nom     Y       4       6       2
1           RA      Dingo   fat     long    N       6       4      -2
```

and I'm running an ANOVA on it like so

```
aov.AMIDS_d <- aov(d.rating ~ group*device*width*length + Error(particip/(device*width*length))+group,data.AMIDS_d)
```

This works ok until I try to print the condition means like so

```
print(model.tables(aov.AMIDS_d,"means"),digits=3)
```

and it says

```
Error in model.tables.aovlist(aov.AMIDS_d, "means") : 
design is unbalanced so cannot proceed
```

According to the design, it ought to be balanced, so I need to check my data structure.  I tried

```
table(data.AMIDS_d)
```

but this gives me SO MANY tables I bust past max.print and can't see a thing.  **How do I limit the tables made to certain columns or only to factors?** It's doing a separate table for each value of the integer-class columns as well, which is a big reason why there are so many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine which columns are the factors, then only pass those columns to `table`:

```
w <- sapply( data.AMIDS_, function(x) is.factor(x) )
table( data.AMIDS_d[, w] )
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked very well.  But it says there are an equal number of observations in all cells, so I've got to find another way to figure out where the unbalance comes from. . .